# Do declarative tags in jsp updates the value of a variable?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

```
<html>
  <body>
      <%int a=10; %>
      <%!int a=20; %>
      <%!int b=30; %>
       The value of b multiplied by a is <%=b*a %>
  </body>
```

The first scriplet tag initializes the value of a = 10.
My question is , does the first declarative tag i.e <%!int a =20; %> update a's value to 20, yielding the result as 600?
Why or Why not?

Answer (score 0):

The following code won't compile because you can not declare another variable with the same name within the same scope:

```
<html>
<body>
    <%
        int a = 10;
    %>
    <%
        int a = 20;
    %>
    <%
        int b = 30;
    %>
    The value of b multiplied by a is
    <%=b * a%>
</body>
```

The correct code would be as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
    <%
        int a = 10;
    %>
    <%
        a = 20;
    %>
    <%
        int b = 30;
    %>
    The value of b multiplied by a is
    <%=b * a%>
</body>
```

Since you are updating the value of `a` with `20`, no matter what value you have initialized it earlier, the previous value will be overwritten i.e. the value of `a` will be considered as `20` giving you the result as:

```
The value of b multiplied by a is 600
```

It works like the following program:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 10;
        a = 20;
        int b = 30;
        System.out.println("The value of b multiplied by a is " + a * b);
    }
}
```

Comment: At a quiz I'm working on, the answer to the question is 300.

Comment: @HarshitChepe - You should not believe anyone/anything without proof .  You should believe what you see as the output. If anyone says something different, challenge him/her and demonstrate the correct way.